# What is the minimum Hamming distance of IBAN (International Bank Account Number), please?

Tags: algorithms, information-theory

Since IBAN is supposed to have IBAN mod 97=1, it should only require changing 2 last digits at minimum, to get another correct IBAN, for example changing 01 to 98, if they are the last digits. Is this line of thinking correct?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Validating_the_IBAN